# CakePHP Undefined index and also removes slashes from URLs

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following Helper that gets the FULL url of the current page in my app:

```
public function selfURL()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';

    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
    {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } 
    else
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
        return $pageURL;  
}
```

However when I use it I get two issues:

1.) The following error:
`Undefined index: HTTPS [APP/View/Helper/LinkHelper.php, line 11]`

2.) The url has slashes missing so instead of getting:
`http://localhost:8888/social/users/add/` I get `http:/localhost:8888/social/users/add` which then blows up my application.

Any ideas why I'm getting these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` *may* not be set if the connection is not HTTPS. Hence use

   ```
   if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')
   ```
2. With the code you have shown this should not be possible. Needs more debugging where exactly the slash goes missing.

Comment: Yeah the slash problem is different see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812173/cakephp-parse-url-causing-issues and I'll accept the answer for this question.